# assigning two different arrays the same subscript in c

Tags: c, arrays

I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for. I am working on a project that involves creating two arrays.  One stores a string, the other stores a number (name and age).  I have to print the arrays, once in the order they are entered, and once alphabetized.  I can alphabetize just fine, but I cannot get the ages to line up with the right name.  Is there a way to assign an array the same subscript as another array in C ?

Comment: How about using a struct?

Comment: Have you learned about `struct` types yet?  If so, use one.  If not, say so.  It means you have to work harder when doing the sorting.

Comment: You must either use structs as shown or use one array as the 'key' values but do the same rearrangement steps to both arrays when sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a struct like this:

```
struct person 
{
    char name[30];
    int age;
};
```

Declare an array like this:

```
struct person record[2];
```

Use it like this (example):

```
strcpy(record[0].name, "Raju");
record[0].age = 24;
```

Now `record[0]` has both a name and an age. When you sort they will stay together.

Comment: I didn't show any array sorting or printing but it seems like you can handle it. If not, I can add more to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array of strings is a 2d matrix, where each row contains a name string, and if you want to keep the two arrays separate, then create a third array of indices, and sort the third array according to the array of names. Then display the names and ages using the third array of indices.

If the array of strings is an array of pointers to strings, you could create a array of indicesto the array of pointers to strings, then sort that array of indices according to the strings, then use the sorted indices to display the two arrays in sorted order.

If using a sort function where you supply a compare function, then create an array of pointers to the array of names (pointer[i] = &names[i]), sort the pointers according to the names, and convert the pointers to indices using pointer subtraction (index = pointer[i] - &name[0]).